# How add padding or change height of bottom tabs RNN

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have to change the height or add padding to the bottom tab, but I really can't, I tried several solutions and I can't find the way...

On the other hand, it's not doing the animated:true animations either, is the place okay?

Use react native navigation (wix) v2

```
Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      bottomTabs: {
        id: 'BottomTabsId',
        options: {
          bottomTabs: {
            backgroundColor: colors.tabBackgroundColor(),
            animate: true,
          },
        },
        children: [
          {
            stack: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'onBoarding',
                  },
                },
              ],
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  icon: homeOff,
                  testID: 'FIRST_TAB_BAR_BUTTON',
                  ...optionsBottomTab,
                },
                topBar: {
                  visible: false,
                  drawBehind: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            stack: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'logIn',
                  },
                },
              ],
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  icon: compassOff,
                  testID: 'SECOND_TAB_BAR_BUTTON',
                  ...optionsBottomTab,
                },
                topBar: {
                  visible: false,
                  drawBehind: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            stack: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'signup',
                  },
                },
              ],
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  icon: circlePlus,
                  testID: 'THIRD_TAB_BAR_BUTTON',
                },
                topBar: {
                  visible: false,
                  drawBehind: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            stack: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'welcome',
                  },
                },
              ],
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  icon: bellOff,
                  testID: 'FOURTH_TAB_BAR_BUTTON',
                  ...optionsBottomTab,
                },
                topBar: {
                  visible: false,
                  drawBehind: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            stack: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'home',
                  },
                },
              ],
              options: {
                bottomTab: {
                  icon: userOff,
                  testID: 'FIFTH_TAB_BAR_BUTTON',
                  ...optionsBottomTab,
                },
                topBar: {
                  visible: false,
                  drawBehind: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

Photo of my problem:

[image]

the + button has a good size, but I need the bottom tab to be larger than the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing BottomTabs height is currently not supported by RNN.
`animate: true` isn't a valid property of a layout node - it should be specified in `options.bottomTabs`. See the `https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/styling?id=options-object-format` for more details on the options object format.